# Best entry level heavy rider bike: Northrock XC00 vs. Mongoose Mushaboom

Tags: heavy

My current weight is 145 kg and I should be 135 kg before summer.
I'm looking for an entry level bike for street riding to help me lose more wight.
I've read a lot about heavy riders and the top suggestions are wide tires, 36 spokes and steel frame.

So far I've narrowed two bikes in Canada that are very similar, the main differences are:

- [Northrock XC00](https://www.costco.ca/northrock-xc00-fat-tire-bike.product.100517805.html) 469.99$
  aluminium frame
  4 inch wide tires
  32 spokes front an back
- [Mongoose Mushaboom](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B07FKMHKYZ) 368.42$
  steel frame
  4.5 inch wide tires
  36 spokes front and back

I know nothing about bikes and I haven't road one in 25 years :-)
I prefer the XC00 even if it's 100$ more than the Moshaboom
It seems sturdier in the photos

Is the XC00 aluminium frame and 32 spokes not recommended for a 135 kg rider?
Is there another bike for 135 kg rider under 500$?

Comment: "best" is too subjective, and varies between riders.  Get a leg over each one and find which is more comfortable.  That will really be the telling point for you.  This question will likely be closed as a Shopping question, because they're considered off topic.  Don't take it personally.  Do enjoy your new bike, whatever you get.

Comment: You better refer to a Local Bike Shop (LBS) to buy a machine that will withstand 145kg because that weight exceeds the standard max. load for most wheels which is more like 120kg.

Comment: And don't assume that a fatbike (~4 inch/100mm tyres) is any stronger because of its appearance..

Comment: Best to lose the 10kg first before buying stuff assuming it will happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have chosen these two bikes based on the information that you know.
Experience riding either of these two bikes is not listed as part of your evaluation criteria.

Deciding which bike to buy is:

1. Very important because:
   A. It is a large purchase
   B. Your choice will have a large effect on how much you enjoy riding. If you get a bike that is not fun to ride you won't want to ride it and it will sit in the garage collecting dust.
2. Very difficult because:
   A. There are so many bikes to choose from sold by several different vendors
   B. There are so many opinions
   C. A good choice will be made based on many factors - some of which you can't know without knowing your own preferences.

Due to the reasons listed above don't buy a bike without riding it first.

This means that you need to visit your local bike shop(s).

A good shop will

1. Give you friendly no purchase required advice.
2. Let you test ride bikes to see what works for you.
3. Be more interested in you getting the right bike than making a sale.

After visiting the bike shop you may have narrowed your search down enough that you can find a place that will rent you the kind(s) of bike you are interested in. This will get you some real saddle time so you can learn what your preferences are and factor them into your buying decision.

Other information from Bicycle Stack Exchange that might be helpful when visiting the bike shop:
[How to choose a bike shop](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/3470/how-to-choose-a-local-bike-shop)
[What do I get when I pay more for a bike?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/64704/what-do-i-get-by-paying-more-for-a-bicycle/64716#64716)
[Choosing my first bike](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/62798/choosing-my-first-bike/62800#62800)